# Restoring deleted submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

Suppose that I have a submodule `dir1/dir2` (created via the steps shown below). How do I restore the submodule `dir2` after having deleted it?

`git submodule update` complains that the submodule does not exist, and `git reset HEAD --hard` restores `dir2` but not its contents. I am creating the submodule in the following way :

```
mkdir dir1
cd dir1/
mkdir dir2

cd dir2/
touch 1.txt
git init
git add 1.txt
git commit -m "test"

cd ..
git init
git submodule add ./dir2/
git commit -m "adding submodule"

rm -r dir2
**** Now how do I restore dir2 and its contents? ****
```

Comment: `git submodule update --init` doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @VonC : No I get a `fatal: repository 'dir1/dir2' does not exist` error message

Comment: And what if you `mkdir dir1/dir2` before the `git submodule update --init`? Also, what version of Git are you using?

Comment: @VonC : No it still complains `fatal: repository`. I guess this must be because the `.git` files are missing from within `dir1/dir2`

Comment: What version of git are you using? .git is not in a submodule root folder for quite some time now.

Comment: @VonC `git version 2.1.3`. But `dir1/dir2` will have git files because I make it a repository (via `git init` from within `dir2`) before I add it as a submodule to `dir1` (see commands above)

Comment: Ok, a nested git repo then, not a submodule. Did you push dir2 to an upstream repo?

Comment: @VonC : No I did not push dir2 to upstream repo.

Comment: Then it is the equivalent of deleting a local repo... nothing much to do beside trying a few of those unerase programs to see if the filesystem has somehow kept a trace of the deleted files.

Comment: @VonC : Ah ok. I think I must be misusing the submodule features. I was just playing with the functionality to see how it works. Thanks

Comment: If you only have a `.gitmodules` file and have deleted the submodules repositories, try this script: https://gist.github.com/aroemen/5027030

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initializing a git repo within `dir2` (`cd dir2; git init`) doesn't make `dir2` a submodule.

It just make `dir2` a nested repo which will be ignored by any parent repo.
Deleting `dir2` means you have no direct way to retrieve its content.

You could have done `git submodule add /another/path/dir2`, with `dir2` a repo *outside* of `dir1`.
Then it would have been possible to restore `dir2`.

Comment: Just to add, for the setup you have mentioned above your original command `git submodule update --init` restores `dir2`

Answer (score 7):

In case you didn't commit the changes (at least)
you can try this. It worked for me

```
git restore path-to-your/submodule-name --recurse-submodules
```

In my case, I think the restore didn't work because it had submodules, and this solved it.

But most important I could restore the undesired changes made to the submodule (a bunch of binaries creating warnings)

Comment: When running git commands there has to be a git repository in the current working directory. For example, if my folder `~/home/myrepo` has a git repository, I need move my current working directory there, to that directory, to run `git status`. Git will return that exact message if you run git status (or any other git command) from a folder that does not contain a git repository

Comment: Maybe you downloaded and extracted a zip or rar file in your "submodules" or "dependencies" folder. That could be the reason there is no git repository in your submodule

Answer (score 3):

Try to "deinit" and "init" all the submodules by the following two commands:

```
git submodule deinit -f .
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: this works when tried after deleting submodule files to restore them..

Answer (score -1):

If you did not commit your deletion you can just
commit all your other local changes and then do

```
git reset --hard
```